# Qt - QVector and Model View - what's the best way to get a custom class from a listView?

Tags: c++, qt, listview, vector, model

I have a custom class called `Foo`, and I store instances of this class in a vector:

```
    class Foo{
    public:
       QString name;
       int second_property;
    }
    //...
    QVector<Foo> foos = {test1, test2, test3};
```

I want to display `name` property  in `listView`, so i create a model, and then fill it with names:

```
in .h
    QStandardItemModel model;
    QStandardItem* root;
    QStandardItem* item;

in .cpp
    root = model.invisibleRootItem();
    ui->listView->setModel(&model);
```

```
foreach(Foo foo, foos){
        item = new QStandardItem(foo.name);
        root->appendRow(item);
    }
```

Now, after I click the item in the UI, I want to have access to this whole `Foo` class, and it's  properties and methods, so I use loop to find my object:

```
void MainWindow::on_listView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    foreach(Foo foo, foos){
        if(foo.name==index.data().toString()){
           qDebug()<<"You found the object! Second property: " + foo.second_property);
        }
    }
}
```

And it does work, but I feel it's not very optimal way of doing it(what if two objects have the same `name`?)

==============

Is there a better solution to this problem? I can ditch QVector or Model/View listView or anything else stupid in this code.
   
TL;DR:
Basically, I want to have one property of an object(`QString name`) displayed in a `listView` (or `listWidget`), and after i click it, I want to have access to every property and method of its class.

==============    
EDIT:

So i made my own model using *QAbstractListModel*:

```
 class myOwnModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    myOwnModel(const QStringList &strings={""}, QObject *parent = nullptr);


    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;

    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex &index) const;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value,
    int role = Qt::EditRole);
    bool insertRows(int position, int rows, const QModelIndex &index = QModelIndex());

private:
     QStringList stringList;
};
```

I still use a loop to fill this model with `QVector<Foo> foos` `name` properties:

```
    myOwnModel* myModel = new myOwnModel();
    for(int row=0; row<foos.size(); row++){
        myModel->insertRows(row,1);
        QModelIndex index = myModel->index(row,0);
        myModel->setData(index,foos[row].name);
    }
    ui->view->setModel(myModel);
```

And then i still use a loop to get a second property of my desired object:

```
    void MainWindow::on_view_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<foos.size();i++){
            if(index.data().toString()==foos[i].name){
                qDebug() << "You found " << foos[i].name + " and the second property is " << foos[i].second_property;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm duplicating data just like with *QStandartItemModel* before, right? 
I tried to use *QAbstractListModel* as [Konstantin T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6853090/konstantin-t) said, but I don't think I understand Models  good enough and used it in a correct way...

Answer (score 1):

Using *QStandardItemModel* almost always is a bad idea. You are duplicating your data in *QVector* and Model. It become very difficult to keep data consistent.

Better way in your case is to use [QAbstractListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html) instead.

Comment: I used QAbstractListModel and edited my post to show my results. Could you look at it?

Comment: @FilthyCasual It depend on where you get the data. Usualy you get data from a file or from a data base and so on, but not from the Vector you've just created.  Though you can store your data in Vector (or any other container) inside you model.

In `MainWindow::on_view_clicked` you don't need to iterate through model. You should use `myOwnModel::data()` to get the data you want.